# SQL Server Count for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

for the table below, how can I write a subquery for my select query 
so that I can return a flag column when the Inv = Esc for a given Num ?

In the example below, the second row is a match as well as the fifth row.
Tried but keep getting boggled.  Thanks.

**Additionally, there should be only one Flag for each Num.

```
    Num  |  Name   |Inv |Esc|Flag
1)  *785*   | AB7851     |155   |496  
2)  *785*   | AB7852     |**496 |496**  |**Hit**
3)  *785*   | AB7853     |518   |496  
4)  *785*   | AB7854     |769   |496  
5)  236 | AB785Q     |**155 |155**      |**Hit**
6)  236 | AB785R     |496   |155  
7)  236 | AB785S     |518   |155  
8)  236 | AB785T     |747   |155  
9)  236 | AB785U     |769   |155
```

Comment: `select *, case when inv = esc then 1 else 0 end as flag from my_table;`

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to add a column to the Table, but rather add a column to a select query pulling the data with a flag.

Comment: Also, it must be for each Num in the group since the Inv #s get used over and over.  So for each Num, where Inv = Esc.....

Comment: Please add the expected result to the question.

Comment: I just added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT t1.*,
       case when Inv = Esc then 'HIT' end  as 'flag'
FROM T t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=71dee124ca65e07373b2d335dd076c82)

If you want to update `Flag` column you can try this.

```
UPDATE T 
SET Flag =  (case when Inv = Esc then 'HIT' end )
```

Comment: `from T tt` -> `from T t2`

Comment: Sorry, all the T tt t1 and t2 boggled me.

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ Ok I saw you edit your question and I edit my answer

Comment: Are you saying I should insert this as is as a subquery in the joins?

Comment: How can I insert this into my existing query?  For example, my query is currenlty:

Select Num, Name, Inv, Esc
From FROM P
Join S on P.Num = S.Num

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ Did you mean you want to update flag colunm?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to do this using a computed column:

```
alter table t add flag as (case when inv = esc then 'hit' end);
```

A computed column is (generally) calculated when the table is queried.  This ensures that the value is always accurate -- without having to create `insert` and `update` triggers.